# Solr replication configuration reports the error 'Invalid URL syntax in "shards" parameter'

Tags: solr

After upgrading from Solr 8.1.1 to 8.8.2 I'm seeing an error on the "follower" instance:

> Unable to create core [sitecore_web_index]
>
> > Invalid URL syntax in 'leaderUrl' with value 'https://searchx.tsta.sxp.local/solr/sitecore_web_index'
> >
> > > Invalid URL syntax in "shards" parameter: null

This is configured with Leader/Follower replication [settings](https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_8/index-replication.html) found in the **solrconfig.xml**.

```
<requestHandler name="/replication" class="solr.ReplicationHandler">
  <lst name="follower">
    <str name="leaderUrl">https://searchx.tsta.sxp.local/solr/${solr.core.name}</str>
    <str name="pollInterval">00:00:20</str>
  </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

I suspect this has to do with a security issue reported and addressed with 8.8.2: [CVE-2021-27905](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2021-27905)

I found an issue reported on Apache's Jira portal with no response: [SOLR-15481](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-15481)

Any steps known to address overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any other documentation available, I was able to get the error to go away with the following entry to the **solr.in.cmd**.

```
set SOLR_OPTS=%SOLR_OPTS% -Dsolr.disable.shardsWhitelist=true
```

Answer (score 0):

By disabling the whitelist check entirely. -`Dsolr.disable.shardsWhitelist=true` update this configuration on `solr.in.sh` file.

Like:

```
SOLR_OPTS="$SOLR_OPTS -Dsolr.disable.shardsWhitelist=true"
```